# Is there a constexpr version of strstr()?

Tags: c++, constexpr

As I understand it, the traditional character array functions, like `strlen`, `strstr` etc are all defined by the C-standard, and since `constexpr` is C++11, they're not declared with it.

However, the [std::char_traits in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) define some equivalent functions like [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/find) (which is essentially a constexpr C++ version of `strchr`, or [copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/copy) which appears to provide something similar to `strcpy`.

But there's no variant of `find` that finds a substring, only a single char. So is there some C++ constexpr equivalent of `strstr` part of the standard anywhere?

Comment: as I understand the `char_traits` they are just meant as basic building blocks for algogrithms. The existing traits already allow customization that you would need for an algorithm that finds a substring

Comment: So basically, people are expected to roll their own?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe you find something with [std::search](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/11/22/how-c17-benefits-from-boost-libraries-part-two/)

Comment: not sure, there is `std::string::substring` which isnt constexpr and my next guess would be string_view, but I am not familiar with them at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view):

```
#include <string_view>

constexpr std::string_view sv1 = "Hello World!";

static_assert(sv1.find("Hello") == 0);
static_assert(sv1.find("World") == 6);
static_assert(sv1.find("olleh") == std::string_view::npos);
```

`std::string_view` constructors are all `constexpr`, so you can construct one from a string-literal, and the `.find()` methods are also `constexpr`.